# Asyncronus React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

**Problem: Asynchronous code causes whole source code to follow asynchrony**

***Example:***

```
    // global scope
    let _variableDefinedInParentScope

    WriteConfiguration(__params) {
    // overSpreading.
    let { data, config } = __params

    // local variable.
    let _fileName, _configuration, _write, _read

    // variable assignment.
    _fileName = config
    _configuration = data

    // if dataset and fileName is not empty.
    if(!_.isEmpty(_configuration) && !_.isEmpty(_fileName)) {

        // create a path you want to write to
        // :warning: on iOS, you cannot write into `RNFS.MainBundlePath`,
        // but `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` exists on both platforms and is writable
        _fileName = Fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + ' /' + _fileName;

        // get file data and return.
        return Fs.readDir(_fileName).then((__data) => {
    console.error(__data)
            // if data is not empty.
            if(!_.isEmpty(__data)) {
                    // return data if found.
                    return __data
            } else {
                // write the file
                return Fs.writeFile(_fileName, data, 'utf8')
                .then((success) => {

                    // on successful file write.
                            return success
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        // report failure.
                        console.error(err.message);
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
                // report failure.
                console.error(err.message)
        })
}
} // write configuration to json file.
```

following are ways to promise handling

- .then((__onAccept)=>{}, (__onReject) => {})
- aync function (__promise) { await WriteConfiguration() }
- .then((_onAccept) => { _variableDefinedInParentScope = __onAccept }

***As far i know third one is useless point as i never encounterd any return because promise is resolving takes time and calling that variable before any resolve will return undefined***

**React-native**
In react-native almost every part of code is syncronus where file writing module's are asynchrony and this is causing trouble for me.

**What i want**
i want to return value from asyncrous to syncrouns code. without any asynchrony chain.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is quit simple by using the

```
 await
```

and

```
 async
```

EXAMPLE:

```
mainFunction(){
  //will wait for asyncroFunction to finish!!
  await asyncroFunction()
}

async asyncroFunction(){
}
```